# rails object is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 2 models, User and Group, they have a many-to-many association through a 3rd model called GroupMembership.  So a user can be a member of many groups and a group can have many users.

when I'm in the rails console everything is working just fine and I can see the users groups by doing this

```
user1 = User.find_by(last_name: "Smith")
user1.groups
```

However, I'm trying to create a new template called mygroups.html.erb and I'm having an issue getting the results to display.

I setup a custom route

```
  get 'mygroups' => 'users#mygroups'
```

then I made the mygroups.html.erb template under the Users view.

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2 col-sm-12">  

      <% if @user.present? %>
        <h5>Groups</h5>
          <ul>
            <% @user.each do |user| %>
              <li>
                <%= user.groups %>
              </li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
      <% end %>

    </div><!--./col-->
  </div><!--./container-->
```

In the users_controller I thought that I would have to do something like this in order to get the @user object

```
  def mygroups
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
    # @groups = @user.groups
  end
```

but I get the following error.  The @user object is nil.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#mygroups 
Couldn't find User with 'id'=
```

Comment: Looks like the params aren't making it to your controller action. Assuming you're using strong params, make sure your params are whitelisted and try logging `params[:id]` to make sure a value is passed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that there is no user with the id passed in the parameter. The id must be a number.

Either pass a parameter for an existing user or you can try

```
  def mygroups
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @groups = @user.groups if @user
  end
```

To avoid getting the error.

Comment: '@user = User.find_by(params[:id])'  worked and also when I tested using     @user = User.find_by(id: 1) I'm not sure why find_by worked and find didn't though.  I'm going to have to read up on them.  Thanks again.